# Change Virtual Machine hardware?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and running Mac OS X Yosemite inside a virtual machine. However inside that virtual mac I need to run Windows inside a Virtual machine. (I am doing something for a friend who owns a Mac and I need to test some stuff before i send it to him). But when I try to create a Windows 10 Virtual Machine inside the Virtual mac it only gives me the option to create a 32-bit Windows Virtual Machine. I need a 64-bit virtual machine though. When I click `About This Mac` it says it is an `iMac (Summer 2001)`. Is there any way to change the hardware of the Mac so it is a newer model so I can run a 64-bit Windows VM on it?

Thanks,

Comment: We cannot help you run OS X on hardware not licensed to run it.  This sounds like a fundamental virtualization hardware problem, in other words, even if this was something we can help with your hardware does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't run a 64-bit VM inside a 64-bit VM anyway. I've tried; I think once you make a 64-bit VM, you're limited to x86 within that VM.